# Reading RAM data from particular location using Driver?

Tags: c, winapi, memory, driver, bsod

i am trying to read RAM data from 0x00000001 and copy it to a file in hard disk (just learning!) so i wrote this and compiled and ran it

```
#include <ntddk.h>

    void DriverUnload(PDRIVER_OBJECT pDriverObject)
    {
        DbgPrint("Driver Unloaded!");
    }


    NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
    {
            DWORD *pointer;
            pointer = 0x00000001;

            DriverObject->DriverUnload = DriverUnload;

        DbgPrint("Driver Loaded!\n");

            DbgPrint("Data at 0x00000000 is %x\n",*pointer);
        return STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }
```

so i got BSOD Luckily i was running this using my Vmware :-)
i always thought that only app programs didn't have rights to read from memory directly.

Now my question is does Driver use direct physical address or virtual address???
i mean what type of value does &pointer return a physical or virtual as in case of driver programming(Ring 1 or 2).i know Ring 3 app will return virtual address.
and yeah i have already starting reading driver books just wanted to know quicker.

Answer (score 1):

No, the kernel uses virtual addresses. This doesn't have to do with rings, they only affect the page access right. If you want to gain access to physical addresses, have a look to "MmMapIoSpace" ([here](http://www.osronline.com/ddkx/kmarch/k106_9j5e.htm)) kernel function.The returned pointer is suitable for memory access.